# How can parse primitive json array contains null with Gson?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, primitive

Json String

```
{"userName":null," msgArr":[null],"numrow":0} //String result
```

Gson

```
new Gson().fromJson(result, MyClass.class);
```

MyClass

```
public String userName;
public int[] msgArr;
...
```

Error Stack

```
at java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Primitive array can't take null values.
at java.lang.reflect.Array.set(Array.java:406)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:78)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
at com.test.dao.RequestBase.onPostExecute(RequestBase.java:79)
```

How can avoid this exception if I can not change json string "msgArr=[null]"?

Comment: Have you tried to change `MyClass` msgArr to `Integer[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user2507946 has the right answer in your comments.

`int` is not nullable  in Java but you can substitute the wrapper class `Integer` to handle null values.

Example

```
public String userName;
public Integer[] msgArr;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder
     .serializeNulls()
     .create();
```

Comment: Yes I'm sorry. I was reading your question from my phone and replied to it from there. After looking from a computer I misred your original question. I apologize.